# Google Apps Script - Calendar removeGuest(*) Unknown email?

Tags: google-apps-script

Simple question I think, hopefully with a simple answer...

I am editing a calendar event from within sheets, specifically adding a guest to the event using addGuest. This is fine, but I'm actually trying to replace a guest already on the event. removeGuest requires a known email address to target and remove, which I don't, so is there a way of simply targeting whatever is currently there? Or am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

there is a method in calendarEvent `getGuestList(false)`. from there you can know the emails of guests. pass true to also include the owner (which you probably dont want to include.)